# ENV Variable not working - Windows 8

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

Trying to add an environment variable called `phantomjs` to my `PATH`:

#### ECHO %PATH%:

```
...;C:\foo\phantomjs.exe
```

but when I run `where phantomjs`, I get

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be the directory

```
...;C:\foo\
```

instead of the file path.

Comment: Sure, no problem. There are similar questions, though. Perhaps try googling a bit longer next time :P